# Troubleshooting Scrollview Scrolling Issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am encountering an issue with the layout of an activity, where the content is not scrolling as intended. Currently, I have a Scrollview implemented within a ConstraintLayout, with a LinearLayout nested inside it. Despite attempting several approaches to resolve this problem, I have been unsuccessful in achieving the desired scrolling behavior.

At this point, I am seeking guidance and assistance in identifying a suitable solution for this issue. I have also experimented with placing the Scrollview within a LinearLayout, but unfortunately, this alternative approach did not yield the desired results either.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, recommendations, or assistance that can be provided to help address this matter effectively. Thank you for your attention and support!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/moreImageButton"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:minWidth="36dp"
        android:minHeight="36dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_bar_black"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagebut"
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:minWidth="36dp"
        android:minHeight="36dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icons8_plus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/hr2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#444"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imagebut"
        ></TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_schedule"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Schedule"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="#000000"    
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hr2" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/hr1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#444"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_schedule"
        ></TableRow>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hr1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lly"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Monday"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_M"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Tuesday"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_T"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Wednesday"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_W"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Thursday"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_TH"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Friday"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_F"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Saturday"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_S"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Sunday"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_SU"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I recommend you to have a look on this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qr5I0uMy3G8 and here for Horizontal scroll: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyJmu_9DMsQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because scroller is as big as its child, the `LinearLayout`. Therefore, there is no need for the scroller to scroll. Try giving your scroller a definite height i.e. 500dp. Finally, the `LinearLayout` should be:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lly"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    >
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to change the height of `RecyclerView(s)` to `300dp`. It works well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/moreImageButton"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:minWidth="36dp"
        android:minHeight="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imagebut"
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:minWidth="36dp"
        android:minHeight="36dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/hr2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#444"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imagebut"
        ></TableRow>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_schedule"
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="Schedule"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textColor="#000000"

        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hr2" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/hr1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#444"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name_schedule"
        ></TableRow>



    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hr1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lly"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Monday"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_M"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Tuesday"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_T"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Wednesday"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_W"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Thursday"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_TH"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Friday"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_F"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Saturday"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_S"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="Sunday"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView_SU"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**The problem is the content of the `ScrollView` is not taller than the screen height. It cannot scroll.**

You can have a look on the tutorial:

- [ScrollView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qr5I0uMy3G8)
- [HorizontalScrollView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyJmu_9DMsQ)

Comment: The reason why I wanted recycler view to wrap content is that, I also wanted to make it not scrollable and add many items whenever the user chose to add new tasks to days. That way I was hoping to have many non scrollable tasks under days and have the page itself scroll. Do you think I can use any other alternatives to recycler view for this case or would you recommend any other method to implement this idea?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you user case. But I suggest that the `ScrollView` scroll by vertical and `RecyclerView`(s) should scroll by horizontal. You are able to use one `RecyclerView` with multiple types of item for displaying all child of the `ScrollView`. But it's harder than the current way.